# Unresolved import Template when building Rocket handlebars example

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am unable to get the Rocket [handlebars example](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/tree/master/examples/handlebars_templates)
to work. These are my Cargo.toml dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "*"
rocket_codegen = "*"
rocket_contrib = "*"
serde = "*"
serde_json = "*"
serde_derive = "*"
```

The errors:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rocket_contrib::Template`
  --> src\main.rs:29:5
   |
29 | use rocket_contrib::Template;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Template` in the root

error[E0599]: no method named `attach` found for type `rocket::Rocket` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:62:10
   |
62 |         .attach(Template::fairing())
   |          ^^^^^^
```

The first error looks for `Template` and can't find it. In the [git repo](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/tree/master/contrib) of the example, it doesn't exist. How is it possible that the example works? I am sure that the Rust code in my main.rs is ok, it's the same as in the example. I think it's only a dependency problem.

I changed my Cargo.toml to:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "*"
rocket_codegen = "*"
serde = "*"
serde_json = "*"
serde_derive = "*"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "*"
features = ["handlebars_templates"]
```

Now I get these errors:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `attach` found for type `rocket::Rocket` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:62:10
   |
62 |         .attach(Template::fairing())
   |          ^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no associated item named `fairing` found for type `rocket_contrib::Template` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:62:17
   |
62 |         .attach(Template::fairing())
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the `handlebars_templates` feature. You can [see this in the example's `Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/3eeae77ed6a7be1c3304a41b7f59b38f6c33c2e6/examples/handlebars_templates/Cargo.toml#L16):

```perl
[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "*" # Not a good idea to use * as version
features = ["handlebars_templates"]
```